# How to make a delay between capturing/bubbling phase

Tags: javascript

I'm learning event phasing of nested elements so I create small project. [Codepen](https://codepen.io/kyauhen/pen/ygxRqV?editors=0010) JS starts on 43rd line.

So here's simple nested divs.

```
<div id="zzz" class="thir">
  0
  <div id="xxx" class="thir">
    0
    <div id="sss" class="thir">
      0
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here what we do with them.

```
const ar2 = [zzz, xxx, sss];
ar2.map(e => {
  e.addEventListener('click', nestedClick, phase);
})

function nestedClick(e) {
  // e.stopPropagation();
  const meow = this;
  const prevColor = this.style.backgroundColor;
  this.style.backgroundColor = '#757575';
  window.setTimeout(() => { meow.style.backgroundColor = prevColor}, 500);
}
```

To visually show how capturing/bubbling works I'd like to change background color and set timeout on each step, wait until it's done and trigger next click with the same strategy.

But here I see after I click on any element event still goes through, changing color and forces all .setTimeout() like at the same time. How can I repair it?

Side question: why e.stopPropagation() works whether it's capturing or bubbling phase?

Thank you for attention!

Comment: It's intended to do so, the propagation of an event goes by first capturing (going untill i clicked body tag) and bubbling (all up again until the first element that got clicked) so if you call in any phase `stopPropagation` that's what it does. It stops the propagation of the event. https://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing

Answer (score 0):

You need to shift the start time of the timers. And for a flashing effect having a second timer would be good.

```js
let counter = 1;
const ar2 = [...document.getElementsByClassName('thir')];
ar2.map(e => {
  e.addEventListener('click', nestedClick);
  e.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
    counter = 1;
  });
});

function nestedClick(e) {
  const prevColor = this.style.backgroundColor;
  debugger;
  setTimeout( () => {
    this.style.backgroundColor = '#757575';
    setTimeout( () => { 
      this.style.backgroundColor = prevColor;
    }, 50 * (counter++));
  }, 500 * (counter++));
}
```

```html
<div id="zzz" class="thir">
  CLICK ME
  <div id="xxx" class="thir">
    CLICK ME
    <div id="sss" class="thir">
      CLICK ME
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```